# Ajax GET request, why does success function not print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have this function that performs a GET request for a given id:

```
var findById= function(id) {
    console.log('findById: ' + id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL + '/' + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log('findById success: ' + data.name);
            currentRaceEntry = data;
            renderList(currentRaceEntry);
        }
    });
};
```

When I enter `sitename/rest/entries/8` it returns a page with the xml for the object requested(as expected). (I can show this code but I dont think the problem is there). When I preform this request the console shows:

```
findById 8
```

My question is why doesn't it show `console.log('findById success: ' + data.name);`? The xml displays in the browser which looks to me like it was successful. So why doesn't the success function appear to be called? Thanks!

EDIT

this is what it looks like:

[image]

The console in the browser is blank

Comment: `dataType: "json",` ... change that to xml.

Comment: open up the console and go to the network tab. Click on the XHR response and inspect it. Most probably you will find that the response has code other than 200.

Comment: @Sirko, i tried that but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: @bagonyi Could you explain where that console is? browser/server?

Comment: It is in the browser. What browser are you using? Usually its Tools / Developer tools, or if Firefox then open up Firebug.

Comment: im getting a 200 response

Comment: What is type of the data you are returning from the server?

Comment: Ok, have you changed dataType: 'xml' in the js?

Comment: yes, the console is still blank

Comment: Add an `error: function () {}` to the ajax call and console.log() in there also.

Answer (score 0):

If you ajax request returns XML data, you need to set `dataType` as "xml".

At that point, the `data` object in the `success` function is an XML fragment, not a javascript objet, and you need to process it as such. The `data.name` property doesn't exist.